# How to show static html pages in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, prerender

Let's say I need to add a landing page to Angular Universal website or a simple html page that doesn't require Angular to be displayed. How can I include such page and allow to navigate to the page within the website? Because it is quite stupid to spawn components for each page in your Angular website

Found some links and some senior developers advise looking into prerender.ts
but I have found any decent examples and explanation

Comment: Prerender indeed fixes your problem but if you want something like landing pages to not use angular , you can configure it via sth like nginx .

Comment: Thank you Mohammad - do you have any examples on how to use prerender in such scenarios? My infrastructure skills are not good enough